# Saving the output of a batch file in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Is there anyway to write the command windows output to a file? To have a transcript if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example, on the command prompt you can do this:

```
dir *.* > c:\temp\a.txt
```

This operation is called 'output redirection'. The output of the above command will go the named file and will overwrite it if it already exists with the results. You can find many examples on the net for that, example: [Redirection.](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt, use >> operator.

For example, If you type below command then output will be saved to output.txt file

dir > output.txt

If you type below then output will be appended to exist file.

dir >> output.txt